# Replacement for RadioGroup in Delphi prism

Tags: winforms, delphi, controls, radio-button, delphi-prism

In Delphi, there is RadioGroup control but not in Delphi Prism. Do you know if there is any similar control for Delphi prism? I have searched my toolbox and all I can find is CheckedListBox. I have been using it and this control is not functioning the same way as RadioGroup control.

Comment: By the way, I think you should include WinForms in your tags since Prism can work with other UI frameworks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In WinForms the standard way to do this is to add a group box and then add radio buttons to that group box.  The radio buttons will automatically be grouped.  But there's nothing like the VCL `ItemIndex` property so you'll have to use the `Checked` property of each radio button to determine which item is selected.

I believe that most of the 3rd party component vendors (e.g. devexpress) fill this gap in the standard component set by providing radio group controls similar to that found in the VCL.